# Animal Stock from Vegetable Stock

Tags: vegetables, stock, bones, chicken-stock

I always seem to accumulate vegetable scraps faster than I do bones, so would it be possible to create a vegetable stock in a pressure cooker, to then create a chicken /beef stock at a later date when the bones are available? Specifically, would there be a considerable loss in flavor, or would there be a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain what you are asking? 
Are you wanting to start a vegetable stock and use it as a base for the bone stock at a later time ?

IMO that would work.

Do a vegetable stock when you have enough vegetable scraps, portion it and freeze it.

When you have enough bones, do the stock using the vegetable stock use made earlier.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. I wasn't sure if too many aromatics would be lost, or if there was a better way of doing it. I hadn't ever heard of anyone preparing stock this way.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, your local grocer/meat department/butcher will put scraps together for you (beef bones, chicken necks, etc) from whatever they are cutting that day. It usually sells for $1/pound (in my area). Just call early! Eliminates the long wait to get enough of what you need/want for your stock.